# Can't remember an old movie and only remember a minor scene

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror, clones

I watched a film that was made before 2009.
In one of the scenes, near the end, a girl (who is either an alien or a clone) and a human man get in a car, her arm is cut by a screw and there is blue stuff under her skin (I assume this is blood) and then because of the cut she is now going to die. 
There is also a young boy who I think is also an alien or a clone and maybe he dies at the end.
It might be based in the future.

I know this isn't anything to go on but if anyone knows even a handful of films with a similar scene it would really help.

Comment: This is probably wrong as details do not match. But it reminds me of [Immortal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortal_%282004_film%29) by Enki Bilal.

Comment: @babou The "blue stuff under her skin" made me think of Immortal too but I think you're about the details not matching.

Comment: An "old movie" is one that was made before 2009? :)

Comment: Possibly the same movie that I have been looking for. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190836/movie-played-on-sci-fi-about-people-with-blue-or-green-blood

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Movie played on Sci-Fi about people with blue or green blood](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190836/movie-played-on-sci-fi-about-people-with-blue-or-green-blood)

Comment: @Adele-NexusofPotlucks - Our policy is only to close as a duplicate once we have a solid confirmation that both questions are asking about the same property.

Answer (score 1):

This movie called [*It Came from Outer Space II*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116658/) (1996)

> Aliens crashland near a small desert town, strewing odd bluish-glowing
> rocks throughout the area. Townfolk notice something is amiss when
> temperatures begin to soar, water disappears, power goes down and
> people seem not to be themselves.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you [edit] in some details as to why you believe this is what the OP is looking for?