# Movie played on Sci-Fi about people with blue or green blood

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie on the Sci Fi Channel sometime between 1992 and 1996. It may have been produced in the late 80s. I vaguely remember watching it as a kid but it took place in the desert. It was most likely low budget and may POSSIBLY be based on a novel.

I think that people in a town started to get sick or started disappearing. I remember a teenage kid getting cut on either a vehicle or construction vehicle and his blood was either blue or green. I also remember towards the end of the movie over a hill in a desert I think, there was some sort of bubble pod or containment that was either lit or blue that was holding people from the town. I think that the main protagonist jumped into it? I don’t remember the plot, only smalls bits and pieces. It reminded me of the body snatchers and how people were acting different/getting sick.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? Any more plot details or any little thing that may help will help us identify this for you.

Comment: Possibly the same movie being asked about in this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51581/cant-remember-an-old-movie-and-only-remember-a-minor-scene ?

Comment: @Otis, sounds like that is the same movie I’m talking about as well.

Comment: @Dana, did that other version of the question jog any additional details from your memory? It's rare that something with enough distinctive detail goes unidentified for so long. Are there any subplots, events, locations, or names that you can remember?

Comment: @Otis, my friend may have possible found it? Invaders from Mars from 1986. Won’t know for sure until I watch it. Based on the trailer and my description it may be it.

Comment: @DanaP -- Thanks for posting back with the update! If this checks out, you should feel free to answer your own question here (this is encouraged behavior for story-id questions), and also to post an answer for the other question that seems the same. Welcome to the stack!

Answer (score 3):

Possibly [The Andromeda Strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andromeda_Strain_(film)):

> After a satellite, a U.S. government project code-named Scoop, crashes near the small rural town of Piedmont, New Mexico, almost all of the town's inhabitants die instantly.

It turns out people are infected with an alien microorganism, which is green and turns their blood into crystals.

There are also bio-isolation installations, both in the town and in the research station tasked with combatting the mircoorganism.

Comment: Dirkt, pretty close but not the movie. I’m thinking it may be The Tommyknockers possibly? Will have to watch that. Otis reply on this thread with another description like mine fits the plot as well.

Answer (score 0):

the movie is "it came from outer space 2" from 1996

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).